# Executing Axios Logic From It's Own File Within Express Server Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm fairly new to Express so am trying to wrap my head around some of the intricacies.

Right now I'm using Axios to Post some data when a specific route is hit.

When I do the Axios post request inside of the route itself, it works fine and logs out the response, i.e.

```
 server.post('/inventory-request', (req, res) => {

    axios.post(base_api_url, data, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
        
    })
```

I then moved the axios request into its own file, './lib/inventory-request.js' (I've omitted some of the config information and request info but I can confirm it's all correct and working)

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const base_api_url = 'some_url';

module.exports = function(){

  const headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/graphql"
        }

  let data = `{
        }`

  axios.post(base_api_url, data, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return 'no'
    })
  
};
```

The updated route then looks like this:

```
server.post('/inventory-request', (req, res) => {

       let inventoryData = inventoryRequest()

       console.log(inventoryData)
        
    })
```

Now when I hit the route, I just get 'undefined' in the log.

I know that this issue is related to async/await and that the console.log is being fired before the Axios post has finished, I'm just having a hard time finding documentation online on the proper way to handle this across two files (the server.js file and the lib/inventory-request.js file).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into a similar issue, here is what I used to get it working:

-server.js becomes

```
 server.post('/inventory-request', async (req, res) => {

   let inventoryData = await inventoryRequest()
        
 })
```

and inventoryRequest.js becomes

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const base_api_url = 'some_url';

module.exports = function(){

  const headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/graphql"
        }

  let data = `{
        }`

  return axios.post(base_api_url, data, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return 'no'
    })
  
};
```

So just a matter of using async/await in the server.js function and returning the entire axios request and not just the axios response in the action file.